# How to convert web elements into JSON string?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to create JSON string of the web elements and values from UI to validate data of UI and database. How can I create JSON string from UI in JAVA.

For example in database it showing below format

{"first name":"abc","last name":”def”,"ID":12345}

But in UI they all are separate elements like **first name   abc
                                                last name    def
                                                ID           12345**
Now my target to convert the web elements into a json format like below 
{"first name":"abc","last name":”def”,"ID":12345}

If anyone knows please response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If do you know all field names you can do something like that:

```
String elemets = "first name abc last name def ID 12345";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
if (elements.contains("first name")) {
    String key = "first name";
    elements = elements.replace(key, "").trim();
    String value = elements.substring(0, elements.indexOf(" ")).trim();
    elements = elements.replace(value, " ").trim();
    jsonObject.put(key, value);
    /*do it for every key, or better, do a method to do it*/
}
```

I know that is really bad code but it works and is easy to undestand.

JSONObject is from org.json, you can grab dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20190722)

This method works only if value has no spaces, if value and key has spaces the only think you can do is get first key, than grub all text between first key and next key but also in this case there is a problem, if one key change position or it miss you gonna get error value or error key. You should write an algorithm that is position invariant. I suggest to save list of all key and check minimum distance from first key and all other keys in order to understand which is second key. Is important delete processed key and value from string in order to work in head of string